# Error en VueJS "Component template requires a root element, rather than just text."

Tags: vue.js

Tengo el siguiente componente global creado con VueJS

```
Vue.component('my-app', {
   props: ["usuario"],
   template: "Hola {{ usuario }}"
})
```

Que recibe el valor de una instancia de Vue, del siguiente modo

```
let app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
     nombre: "alejandro"
   }
})
```

Al que finalmente en la vista invoco de este modo

```
<my-app :usuario="nombre"></my-app>
```

Pero obtengo un error que dice lo siguiente

```
"[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Component template requires a root element, rather than just text.

1  |  Hola {{ usuario }}
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

found in

---> <MyApp>
       <Root>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la documentación de VueJS, justo [aquí](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Fragment-Instances-removed) que indica lo siguiente

Todos los elementos deben tener un elemento raíz ya que las *Fragments Instances* han sido removidos y ahora la declaración del elemento raíz debe ser de modo explícito es decir escribirlo para identificarlo

Por lo que el componente mencionado mas arriba debería ser así

```
Vue.component('my-app', {
   props: ["usuario"],
   template: "<div> Hola {{ usuario }} </div>"
})
```

Para el caso anterior, la etiqueta `div` se vuelve el elemento raíz que envuelve la impresión de `usuario`